# Pass Object to Templated HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an object I wold like to pass to a templated HTML file.  If I use a simple variable, all is fine, as these work:
on the server side I have the following at the top of code.gs:

```
//Define this here globally so it is accessed in the HTML Template
    var passedFestival = ' ';
    var passedSID = ' ';
    var passedRID = 'FALSE';
```

in the HTML file I have:

```
<script>

  var passedFestival = '<?!= passedFestival ?>';
  var passedSID = '<?!= passedSID ?>';
  var passedRID = '<?!= passedRID ?>';

</script>
```

I can use these in later code and get the appropriate value.  I want to also use an Object, which is the result of reading a couple rows from the spreadsheet, and basically results in the following outside any function, same as the other variables, above:

```
var testformOptions = [];
testformOptions['currencies'] = [{"currency":"CAD", "default":false, "defaultOption":"Interac", "paymentOptions":"Cheque|Credit Card|Interac|PayPal", "sheetrow":2}, {"currency":"USD", "default":true, "defaultOption":"PopMoney", "paymentOptions":"Cheque|Credit Card|PayPal|PopMoney", "sheetrow":3}];
testformOptions['meals'] = {"use":true, "required":false, "default":"Omnivore", "values":"Omnivore|Vegan"};
```

in the HTML file I can reference the object's individual values:

```
if ('<?!= testformOptions.currencyOptions.use ?>') {
  $("#currencies").show();
}
```

But I would rather copy the object over completely and reference it as part of the client side data.  I have tried a few things, most of which I understand why they didn't work, but I thought this would:

```
var formOptions = jQuery.extend(true, {}, <?!= testformOptions?>;
```

I have tried saving the data to a variable as json, but that didn't work since I have single quotes and other special characters in my final object.

Is there any way to get an object passed into an object on the client side outside using `google.script.run` to pass it after loading?  I am reading the spreadsheet data as part of the initial doGet so I figured it may be faster to use templated HTML and pass the object.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the reply, I have working code.  The final sample reads as follows.  Some items are left out to allow focusing on the important parts.
*Code.gs:*

```
var passedSID = ' ';
var passedRID = 'FALSE';
function doGet(passed) {

  if(passed.parameter.rid && passed.parameter.msid){
    // A registration ID and Spreadsheet ID were passed so this is to edit an existing registration
    passedSID = passed.parameter.msid;
    passedRID = passed.parameter.rid;
    var registrationValues = getRegistrationValues(passedSID, passedRID);
  }
  else if(passed.parameter.msid){
    // A Spreadsheet ID was passed so this is to complete a new registration
    passedSID = passed.parameter.msid;
  }

  //get the form options from the appropriate spreadsheet file
  //getFormOptions() is from Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge
  //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge
  testformOptions = getFormOptions(passedSID);

  //Create the HTML template
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  template.data = JSON.stringify(testformOptions);

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Registration Form').setWidth(620).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate()
      .getContent();
}
```

*Index.html:*

```
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100" rel="stylesheet">
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="mybody">
  <form>
   <!-- Boring form html -->
</form>
</div>
  </body>
</html>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var formOptions = $.extend(true, {}, <?!= data ?>);
</script>

<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquery_cloneform_js').getContent(); ?>
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

And in JavaScript.html:

```
<script>
  var passedSID = '<?!= passedSID ?>';
  var passedRID = '<?!= passedRID ?>';

  // use onload to call initialization after the document loads
  window.onload = setForm;
function setForm(){

  var optionArray = [];
  var defaultOption = '';

  if (formOptions.currencyOptions.use) {
    $("#currencies").show();
    //Set the options for the currency
    var options = formOptions.currencyOptions.values;
    defaultOption = formOptions.currencyOptions.defaultOption;
    optionArray =  options.split("|");
    setSelectOptions('regcurrency', optionArray, defaultOption);

    var options = formOptions.currencies[1].paymentOptions;
    defaultOption = formOptions.currencies[1].defaultOption;
    optionArray =  options.split("|");
    setSelectOptions('paymentMethod', optionArray, defaultOption);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a following answer?

#### Modification points :

```
var testformOptions = [];
testformOptions['currencies'] = [{"currency":"CAD", "default":false, "defaultOption":"Interac", "paymentOptions":"Cheque|Credit Card|Interac|PayPal", "sheetrow":2}, {"currency":"USD", "default":true, "defaultOption":"PopMoney", "paymentOptions":"Cheque|Credit Card|PayPal|PopMoney", "sheetrow":3}];
testformOptions['meals'] = {"use":true, "required":false, "default":"Omnivore", "values":"Omnivore|Vegan"};
```

1. About the above script, `testformOptions` is defined as an array. So `testformOptions['currencies']` and `testformOptions['meals']` cannot be imported. So please modify from `var testformOptions = [];` to `var testformOptions = {};`.
2. When it passes the object, please use `JSON.stringify()`.

The scripts reflected above modifications are as follows.

#### code.gs :

```
function doGet() {
  var testformOptions = {};
  testformOptions['currencies'] = [{"currency":"CAD", "default":false, "defaultOption":"Interac", "paymentOptions":"Cheque|Credit Card|Interac|PayPal", "sheetrow":2}, {"currency":"USD", "default":true, "defaultOption":"PopMoney", "paymentOptions":"Cheque|Credit Card|PayPal|PopMoney", "sheetrow":3}];
  testformOptions['meals'] = {"use":true, "required":false, "default":"Omnivore", "values":"Omnivore|Vegan"};

  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  t.data = JSON.stringify(testformOptions);
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

#### index.html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<p id="disp"></p>
<script>
    var data = $.extend(true, {}, <?!= data ?>);
    $('#disp').text(JSON.stringify(data));
</script>
```

#### Result :

```
{
  "currencies": [
    {
      "currency": "CAD",
      "default": false,
      "defaultOption": "Interac",
      "paymentOptions": "Cheque|Credit Card|Interac|PayPal",
      "sheetrow": 2
    },
    {
      "currency": "USD",
      "default": true,
      "defaultOption": "PopMoney",
      "paymentOptions": "Cheque|Credit Card|PayPal|PopMoney",
      "sheetrow": 3
    }
  ],
  "meals": {
    "use": true,
    "required": false,
    "default": "Omnivore",
    "values": "Omnivore|Vegan"
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I thought I had tried this already. After playing around with your code, I found there is defiantly an order to follow.  The script section above needs to happen in the initial HTML file and prior to loading any other files with something like `<?!= HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>`

Comment: @Karl_S Thank you for your additional information. Can we see your current whole sample script?

Comment: I edited the original post to include enough of the final code to serve as a sample.  Note that my initial comment pertains to including script as I am able to include a file for CSS, as shown in my edit.

Comment: @Karl_S Thank you for sharing your current scripts. I think that this will be able to be applied for various scenes.